# How to open a chrome window using a java program in a full screen mode/size?

Tags: java, google-chrome

I am working on a program that opens multiple URLs in multiple chrome windows where I am supposed to take the screenshots of those windows and write to a file. 
So far I am able to open the URLs in different chrome windows but I don't know how to open those windows in a full screen mode/size.So that screenshots can be taken properly.Can anyone help? 
My code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                try{//using try-catch as the target system might be of 32 bit or 64 bit
                    Process p = runtime.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe -new-window "+url);
}catch(Exception ex){
                    Process p = runtime.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe -new-window "+url);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "path/to/chrome.exe";
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr1 = rt.exec(path + " --app=https://url1.com --start-maximized");
        Process pr2 = rt.exec(path + " --app=https://url2.com --start-maximized");
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say but still it does not open in full size. Before it used to open in any random size but after your solution it opens in a fixed size that's it.

Comment: Try closing all the instances of chrome first and then run the program.